# Browse a file with robot - sometimes browse the wrong file

Tags: java, selenium

I need to browse a file from my PC to the web
I use the robot method

```
browseButton.click();
test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Buttom is clicked");

setClipboardData**("C:\\SLT file\\small.stl**");
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

public void setClipboardData(String string) 
{
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
```

sometimes it is work good and sometimes it display a msg:

[image: message trying to open the file 'v']

Do you know why is it like that?

Comment: when does it perform well?

Comment: It looks like it sees the file name `v`, which means it did not get the control key. You are running your robot much faster than a human. You should probably introduce some delays.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open this file in a browser, in this way:

```
@Test
public void shouldOpenLocalFileInABrowser() throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("file:///C:/tmp/ala.csv");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.quit();

}
```

This is an outcome of the above code:
[image]